# Enable SNMP on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, snmp

I am trying to enable SNMP version 3 with a single ready-only user on Mac OS X 10.8.5 so that I can remotely monitor the health of the computer. When I attempt a local `snmpwalk`, this message is returned:

```
No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
snmpwalk: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)
```

Below are the exact steps I executed to get to this point. What am I missing? FYI, the username I am using is rouser with password 12345678

```
sudo snmpconf -i
```

creates `/usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf` with permissions `-rw-r--r--   1 root  staff    484 Sep 25 14:44 snmpd.conf` and contains:

```
# snmpd.conf
#   - created by the snmpconf configuration program
#
# SECTION: Access Control Setup
#
#   This section defines who is allowed to talk to your running
#   snmp agent.

# rouser: a SNMPv3 read-only user
#   arguments:  user [noauth|auth|priv] [restriction_oid]
rouser  rouser priv
```

create user:

```
sudo net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -a 12345678 -x 12345678 -X AES -A SHA rouser
```

that creates `/var/db/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` with permissions `-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    46 Sep 25 14:44 snmpd.conf` and contains:

```
createUser rouser SHA "12345678" AES 12345678
```

that command also updates `/usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf` to this (last line added):

```
# snmpd.conf
#   - created by the snmpconf configuration program
#
# SECTION: Access Control Setup
#
#   This section defines who is allowed to talk to your running
#   snmp agent.

# rouser: a SNMPv3 read-only user
#   arguments:  user [noauth|auth|priv] [restriction_oid]

rouser  rouser priv
rouser rouser
```

enable SNMP:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.net-snmp.snmpd.plist
```

that command changed the permissions of `/var/db/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` to `-rw-------   1 root  wheel  1420 Sep 25 15:04 snmpd.conf` and changed its contents to:

```
#
# net-snmp (or ucd-snmp) persistent data file.
#
############################################################################
# STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP
#
#          **** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE ****
#
# STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP
############################################################################
#
# DO NOT STORE CONFIGURATION ENTRIES HERE.
# Please save normal configuration tokens for snmpd in SNMPCONFPATH/snmpd.conf.
# Only "createUser" tokens should be placed here by snmpd administrators.
# (Did I mention: do not edit this file?)
#


usmUser 1 3 0x80001f888098ad4f304567245400000000 "rouser" "rouser" NULL .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.1.1.3 0x22051a77e41dc526caebc92dc387257482bcd$
setserialno 1673336648

##############################################################
#
# snmpNotifyFilterTable persistent data
#
##############################################################


##############################################################
#
# ifXTable persistent data
#
ifXTable .1 14:0 18:0x $
ifXTable .2 14:0 18:0x $
ifXTable .3 14:0 18:0x $
ifXTable .4 14:0 18:0x $
ifXTable .5 14:0 18:0x $
ifXTable .6 14:0 18:0x $
ifXTable .7 14:0 18:0x $
ifXTable .8 14:0 18:0x $
##############################################################

engineBoots 1
oldEngineID 0x80001f888098ad4f304567245400000000
```

try querying the system locally:

```
snmpwalk -v 3 -u rouser -l authPriv -a MD5 -A 12345678 -x DES -X 12345678 localhost .1
```

that returns:

```
No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
snmpwalk: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)
```

/var/log/snmpd.log:

```
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 61: Error: example config COMMUNITY not properly configured
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 62: Error: example config NETWORK not properly configured
net-snmp: 2 error(s) in config file(s)
NET-SNMP version 5.6
Authentication failed for rouser
Authentication failed for rouser
```

disable SNMP in the meantime

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.net-snmp.snmpd.plist
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, delete the duplicate rouser line from snmpd.conf, leaving just the "rouser rouser priv" line.

Second, note that you created your user with AES:

`sudo net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -a 12345678 -x 12345678 -X AES -A SHA rouser`

But are trying to walk using DES:

`snmpwalk -v 3 -u rouser -l authPriv -a MD5 -A 12345678 -x DES -X 12345678 localhost .1`

That's just not going to work. Swtich to `-x AES` in the snmpwalk, and there's a much better chance it will work. ;-)

Comment: I also had to switch my authentication method to from MD5 to SHA: `-a SHA`.